# Updating Pinterest Embeds in Preact App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, pinterest, preact

I have a component that needs to load changing Pinterest embeds based on the state of the app. Pinterest embeds consist of an `<a>` tag that gets transformed into a complex layout within a `<span>` tag through the use of the async script at the bottom of my HTML (available [here](https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js)). However, I am having trouble figuring out how, upon a re-render with updated props, to clear the old `<span>` embed and re-run the script to render the new embed. Thanks!

My component:

```
const PinterestEmbed = ({ location, size }) => (
    <div stye="text-align: center;margin: auto;">
        <a
            data-pin-do="embedPin"
            data-pin-width={size}
            href={location}>
            Pin via Pinterest
        </a>
    </div>
);

export default PinterestEmbed;
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution here is to switch to a full component:

```
export default class PinterestEmbed extends Component {
  // keep a reference to the link so we can update it:
  linkRef = el => {
    this.link = el;
  };
  // never re-render using virtual dom:
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }
  // instead, we'll handle location changes ourselves:
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.location!==this.props.location) {
      this.link.href = nextProps.location;
      // do something to tell Pinterest to update (not sure how they expose it):
      Pinterest.reInitialize(this.link);
    }
  }
  render({ location, size }) {
    return (
      <div stye="text-align: center;margin: auto;">
        <a
            ref={this.linkRef}
            data-pin-do="embedPin"
            data-pin-width={size}
            href={location}>
          Pin via Pinterest
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```